# What ways are available to develop application for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I'm just learning how to develop an application for Sharepoint.

As far as I can see there are three types of integration into Sharepoint possible:

- Sandboxed Solution (limited resource access but easy to install etc)
- Farm Solution (installation only available from administrator)
- Standard application (maybe .net MVC) with referencing the Sharepoint assembly to access the SPS functionality

Is that correct and complete or am I missing something?

Comment: There are many other things like Timer jobs, Event handlers, Client Applications in Silverlight or .net etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to develop for SharePoint depending on your scope, requirements, etc. My knowledge is more in the SP2007 realm than 2010 and my answer reflects that.

**JavaScript**

Using Content Editor Web Parts you can customize the look of SharePoint, interact with List Data and do some interesting UI effects just using jQuery and the SPServices Plugin. These solutions don't require package and deployment.

**Custom Content Type**

These can be created through the SharePoint UI or defined through custom XML documents and deployed via WSP. Essentially these are just a collection of field definitions that are related in some logical way. Content types can be added to a list to have all the fields automatically available. In addition, they provide a convenient way of mixing and matching data in the same list (think of roll-ups or backing up list data) though I've never used them in this way.

**Event Receiver**

Event Receivers can be created to respond to specific events in SharePoint. If you attach an Event Receiver to a list, you can listen for and respond to events like an item or attachment being added, updated, deleted in both a synchronous (-ing) fashion - so you can implement validation and cancel the operation - or asynchronously (-ed) - to do some post-processing once SharePoint is done processing the item. Event Receivers are processed by the Front-End SharePoint server which handled the request which triggered the event. This is different than Timer Jobs and Workflows which are executed by any server in the farm that happens to be available.

Further, Event Receivers can be attached to lists based on their type (apply to all lists of this ID type) or they can be associated with a Content Type and become associated with a list that way (when the content type is added to the list, so too is the event receiver added).

*Feature Receivers* are a special kind of Event Receiver in that they respond to a Feature 
being activated or deactivated to do some additional work. Many people refer to this extra work as Feature Stapling since it lets you perform additional tasks on-demand that couldn't otherwise be done using just XML documents.

**Timer Job**

A Timer Job is a piece of code that is run on a schedule. It's not executed in the W3WP process like Event Receivers are but rather via the TimerService. Because of this, certain features or values are missing from the SPRequest object. Developing Timer Jobs is more difficult and, in practice, more error prone, more difficult to debug, etc. than Event Receivers.

**Workflow**

Workflows can be created using SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio. The major difference between these are features available to you at design time. SharePoint Designer Workflows are easier to create and get going but tend to be buggy in SharePoint 2007. Further they are not easily packaged and deployed across environments but rather are associated directly to the list in which you created them (in 2007; in 2010 there is extended capability to allow packaging or even migration into Visual Studio for more complicated customization).

Using Visual Studio gives you more depth and capability but like Timer Jobs they are often difficult to "get right" and they are also processed by the Timer Service process.

**Web Part**

A custom Web Part is very similar to a regular ASP.NET web part with some extended capability within the SharePoint context. You have access to the SPRequest object and thus all the contextual information (current user, current list/web/site, etc.) to do your work. You can access external databases, make use of most ASP.NET controls, etc.

**Custom ASPX Page**

If a Web Part isn't sufficient for your needs or you want control over the full page, you can create SharePoint-enabled web pages. These are standard ASP.NET pages decorated with the proper SharePoint master page and deployed into a subdirectory of the hive LAYOUTS directory. With this you have similar access to the current request state as with a Web Part but you have more control over the entire page render.

**Custom Web Application**

If you have need for a standalone application, you can still take advantage of SharePoint's authentication and authorization tools without running directly in its context. To do this, create an IIS Web Application and set the Application Pool Identity to the same as SharePoint. Alternatively you could make a virtual directory within your SharePoint application pool but this is generally not recommended. You will still be constrained to using the .NET Framework 2.0 runtime if you want to use the SharePoint Object Model at all. This setup seems rarely used in the field since most of the time you can accomplish your needs by just using custom ASPX pages or web parts.

**Regarding your specific questions:**

Sandboxed solutions are just a special type of solution that restricts the namespaces your web part, etc. have access to. For instance your code can't reach out to access lists outside of its permission area. It can't send email on your behalf. You can increase your rights by using custom permission sets but this is an advanced topic. I just wanted to point out "sandboxed solution" isn't a type in and of itself, it just describes a restriction where previously none existed (SP 2007 GAC-deployed solutions).

Regarding your question regarding an MVC application using the SharePoint Object Model, like I mentioned you are still restricted to running in .NET 2.0 runtime.

**EDIT: I forgot (at least) one more option!**

**List Service / Other ASMX Services**

SharePoint has a number of web services you can consume to interact with Lists among other things. In this case, your application can be developed using any technology (or runtime!) you wish as long as it knows how to consume the ASMX services. The functionality available isn't as rich as using the Object Model directly (which is why I often forget to consider it) but it does allow your code to be more decoupled from the SharePoint environment itself. In 2010 there are a lot more options for Client Services to provide even greater functionality.

Comment: I forgot about List Services! I edited to add a blurb about them. Maybe I should look up some links and edit some more or is this enough to go on?

Comment: You already provided much more information as I expected and thanks for the addition as well! I would be happy if you add more information of course! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For developing a solution in visual studio you can go for Sandbox solution and farm solution. If you are having SharePoint 2013, then you will have another better option which is App Part development.

Since Sandbox solution is depricated from SharePoint 2013 onwards, i suggest you should not go with Sandbox solutions. Better to go with App Part development.